# How to allow devise to save user if a specific email (blank email) already exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a devise user model.When a user is to be created there is no email required (email is optional).I can create the user without email (blank email ) for the first time.When i add a user second time the error shows up

`duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_accounts_on_email"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=() already exists.`

I think this happen if a blank email already exists.

Is there a way to validate the uniqueness only if the email is not blank and i can add as many user with blank emails?

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable, :omniauthable

protected
 def password_required?
  false
 end

def email_required?
  false
end

end
```

Comment: Can you post your model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in your migration file that created the users you will find the line:

```
add_index :users, :email, unique: true
```

One way to remove this is removing the index complete and add it again without uniqueness:

```
remove_index :users, :email
add_index :users, :email
```

Now it won't check for email uniqueness and you can handle this by yourself whenever and wherever you want.

Comment: You have to remove the uniqueness from the database level otherwise you will never be able so save multiple blank emails.

Comment: `validates_uniqueness_of :email, conditions: -> {where.not(:email => '')}` adding to model now helped me after the change you gave , thank you!

Comment: Great, with validations at the model level you can control it better.